# Regex for input string for version numbers

Tags: php

In my application user can add version number in input field, suppose initially he add a version number like 1.0.1 and he have to enter any higher version number next time, how can I validate it in php.

Different type of version numbers
1.0
1.0.1
1.01

it can be any combination

can anyone help me here?

Comment: you mean you wanted to validate that the new version number input is higher than the old one?

Comment: keep version as major minor and revision ... and select max from all

Comment: yes I want to validate that the new version number input is higher than the old one.

Comment: where u r storing/keeping previous version? and how?

Comment: we keep previous version number in DB

Comment: select max(autoid), versionNumber from versiontable ;

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111510/regex-for-input-string-for-version-numbers/21112175#21112175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$version="1.0.1.1";
$versionnew="1.0.1.0";

//explode the version to be able to compare each and every part of the version
$versionArray = explode(".",$version);
$versionnewArray = explode(".",$versionnew);

//the maximum depth of comparison
$limit = min(count($versionArray),count($versionnewArray));

for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++){
    if($versionArray[$i] == $versionnewArray[$i]){
        continue;
    }else if($versionArray[$i] > $versionnewArray[$i]){
        echo $versionnew . " should be newer than " . $version;
    }else echo $versionnew . " is newer than " . $version;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to get going

```
$newVersion= "1.2"; //get a string reference to your version here
$oldVersion = "1.3";    
$piecesNew = explode(".", $newVersion); //This will give you an array existing of [1,2]
$piecesOld = explode(".", $oldVersion); //This will give you an array existing of [1,3]
//Do some checking here for each number
```

Comment: Yes this will solve my problem at one extend, but what if version number is like 1.0.1 or 1.0.0.1 or 1,etc... I need a generalize way to handle it.

Comment: For that you need some if then else statements. To start off you can check if both arrays have the same lenght. If so compare them, if not compare them and if they are equal the last position of the new pieces must be set